# Objective-C/Carbon Application Crashes randomly on MacOS 10.7

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, macos-carbon

My objective-C/Carbon application is crashing randomly. Can anybody help me by looking at the following crash log about what might be causing the crash.Recently, I have added some code to bring the window on top.

```
if(!IsWindowActive(gWindow))
{
   ProcessSerialNumber psn = {0, kCurrentProcess};
   OSErr err = SetFrontProcess(&psn); 
}
```

Would something in this piece of code be causing the crash. Crash is random.When I run it  20-25 times, it might crash once. OS is Mac 10.7

```
Crashed Thread:  2  Dispatch queue: NSPersistentUI Work

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000020

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: setExternalPublicProperties:
objc[3446]: garbage collection is OFF


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x02032c22 mach_msg_trap + 10    
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x020321f6 mach_msg + 70    
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x02bb2c3b _CGSGetWorkspace + 96    
3   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x02bb2bd9 CGSGetWorkspace + 220    
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x0076f184 WindowData::OnActiveSpace() + 128    
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x0076f1e1 HIWindowIsOnActiveSpace + 29    
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00530667 HIApplication::GetWindowToActivateStartingAt(OpaqueWindowPtr*, unsigned char) + 41    
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x005306d4 HIApplication::GetWindowToActivate() + 64    
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x004a0ec8 HIApplication::EventHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 5552    
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00628920 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36    
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x004a4803 _ZL23DispatchEventToHandlersP14EventTargetRecP14OpaqueEventRefP14HandlerCallRec + 1602    
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x004a3c80 _ZL30SendEventToEventTargetInternalP14OpaqueEventRefP20OpaqueEventTargetRefP14HandlerCallRec + 482    
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x004b8aa9 SendEventToEventTarget + 76    
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x004c8dea _ZL23RequestWindowToActivatev + 96    
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x004b7dbf HIApplication::HandleActivated(OpaqueEventRef*, unsigned char, OpaqueWindowPtr*) + 291


Thread 2 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: NSPersistentUI Work

0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x01bd0d47 objc_msgSend + 23    
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x09802427 __-[NSPersistentUIManager setPublicProperties:forWindowID:]_block_invoke_1 + 260    
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x01e71e11 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15    
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x01e73797 _dispatch_queue_drain + 224    
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x01e7363c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 47    
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x01e72e44 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 187    
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x01f25b24 _pthread_wqthread + 346    
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x01f276fe start_wqthread + 30
```

Comment: Have you tried running your app under Instruments with its Zombies feature enabled? It may give you a clue.

Comment: And also use the memory debugging features in Xcode: Edit Schemes > Diagnostics Tab > Memory Management. Just tick all and run under the debugger

Comment: Actually, the problem is that it never crashes on my development machine. Thats why I wanted to know if someone can get any clue from the crash log about what event might be causing the crash in test machine.

Comment: @VikramSingh: Everything Jay and I suggested is a possible means to cause the crash to happen reliably.

Comment: Thanks Peter...I tried to get the crash log with the debug version of the application and it had quite a lot of information :)